# How to show address bar again after exiting fullscreen on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, fullscreen, address-bar

I use a HTML5 fullscreen plugin (https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin) to view a website on request in fullscreen.

This works great - however, when I exit the fullscreen via plugin, I only see the very top bar, but not the address bar.

If I rotate the device into landscape and back into portrait mode, the address bar shows up, but I cannot expect users to know (and do) that.

How can I tell Chrome on Android to show up the address bar after programatically exiting fullscreen?

---

**Initial state**
[image]

**Address bar missing after exiting fullscreen**
[image]

Comment: *Why* do you want to reveal the address bar?

Comment: For once, because it is good usability behaviour to reset the initial state when you exit fullscreen. But more concretely, you need the address bar to bookmark, navigate between tabs, etc

Comment: Does programmatically scrolling on top make the addressbar show? Something like `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` might work. Let me know if it does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am no longer working on this project...

Answer (score 1):

To force the address bar to show again try `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to force the browser to scroll which reveals the address bar.
This is a kind of hacky solution.

Comment: It will most probably work - however, I cannot test it since I am no longer working on this project. Would it make sense to select your response as answer nevertheless?